# python call method from outside the class

Tags: python, class

how can I in python call method from outside which is situated inside the class?

```
class C():    
    def write():
        print 'Hello worl'
```

I thought that `>>> x = C` and `>>> x.write()` must work but it doesn't.

Comment: You forgot the parentheses after C.  Type `x = C()` instead of `x = C`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont you need to have self in your definition?

```
class C(object):    
    def write(self):
        print 'Hello world'
```

Now it should be fine, i.e.

```
x = C()
x.write()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you where defining x, you forgot to put the parantheses after the class, this made so x literally was equals to the class C and not the object C.

```
class C:
    def write():
        print "Hello worl"

x = C() # Notice the parantheses after the class name.
x.write() # This will output Hello worl.
```