# Using a method class outside the class & inside the class

Tags: python, class, methods

I am trying to truly understand what is going on with class methods in python and came across to the following that I can not understand.

My code:

```
class exampleclass():

    def __init__(self,text):
        self.text = text

        self.firstletter = text[0]

        # the method has to be run --> with ()
        self.lastletter = self.methodlast()

        # the option that I used to use:
        self.secondletter = self.method2(self.text)

        # with the variable last letter I do something else
        # The order is important. lastletter is already defined here.

    def methodlast(self):
        return self.text[-1]

    def method2(self, text):
        return text[1]

    def methodX5(self):
        # addind a variable to the class
        self.longstring = self.lastletter * 5
```

My intention is create attributes of the class method by method and I also want the methods to be able to individually be accessed from outside the class.

ideally I would like:

```
cla_ins = exampleclass("this is a text")
```

But I also want to use the method independently of a class instance:

```
second_letter  = exampleclass.method2("whatever")
```

Using the method calling the class is not OK:

```
try:
    a =exampleclass.method2("whatever")
    print(a)
except Exception as e: 
    print(str(e))
```

gives error:

```
method2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```

Using the instance works:

```
try:
    a = cla_ins.method2("whatever")
    print(a)
except Exception as e: 
    print(str(e))
```

How should a class be built to have methods to be accessed from inside the class and also from outside?

From inside I mean:

```
self.secondletter = self.method2(self.text)
```

From outside I mean:

```
a = exampleclass.mehtod2("whatever")
```

It looks like I can only call a method class using an instance of the class. That would make my whole reasoning void. i.e. I use the method with instances or I don't use the method from outside, right?

So far other links consulted:

- [Improve Your Python: Python Classes and Object Oriented Programming](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/)
- [How do I use a method outside a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943582/how-do-i-use-a-method-outside-a-class)
- [Issue calling method outside class python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316211/issue-calling-method-outside-class-python)
- [python call method from outside the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282935/python-call-method-from-outside-the-class)

Comment: you did a typo it is method2 not mehtod2

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you didn't make a typo. mehtod2 != method2

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like I can only call a method [on a] class using an instance of the
>   class.

That is true.

You can use [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod) annotation to create a class method though. Note, that a class method cannot change instance state (so `method2` in your example is ok to become a class method by adding the annotation and by changing `self` parameter in the signature to `cls` for clarity).

Comment: Sorry guys, typo is corrected. question is partially independent of the typo

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 0):

I think , you have a typo in your code. You have made the method `method2` but calling the method `mehtod2` .